# Create a string attribute on a method and then fire when called by another method via attribute

Tags: c#

I was put onto this path when asking another Q on another topic but I'm struggling to see how it's possible. So if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic! and much appreciated.

So basically in my UI layer(external site) I'm trying to reduce hard coded strings and conditional logic.

The below code receives the value from a querystring (which is a controller name on a web api).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string addonType = Request.QueryString["addOnType"];
    string webName = Request.QueryString["webName"];

        //Addon does exist, so does the one being requested exist
        if (contentFacade.AddonExists(addonType)) 
        {
            //Determine whether its a list or single page
            contentFacade.GetContent(addonType, webName);
        }
        else
        {
            //Requested addon does not exist
            Response.Redirect("/notifications/404/");
        }
}
```

At that point it fires a method: `contentFacade.GetContent(addonType, webName);`

Which points to my facade that builds content and in that facade I have multiple methods like:

- GetBlogPosts
- GetNews
- GetServices

All the methods point to their respective class's (DTO's) that fetch json from the web-api and then I convert that into HTML on the UI end.

In an ideal world I would like to add an attribute on any of those methods with there controller names, like so:

```
["blog"] //controller name in the attribute
public string GetBlogPosts() 
{
   //Code ommitted
}
```

On the front-end I would only ever call "GetContent"

```
public string GetContent(string controllerName, string singleItemName = "") 
{
    //HERE I would like to call the method by the attribute of the controller name (string value)

    //Maybe something like this ...
    return this.attribute(typeOf(controllerName)).Invoke().Value();
}
```

The idea eventually is to keep it super maintainable. Some logic will be removed out, so the UI (external sites) don't need to know any information other than it receives some cool content.

All the information is being pulled from my custom built CMS with secure app keys. It's just delivering of the content in a robust manner that's challenging.

**So to re-cap, could any one point me in direction of adding an attribute to a method and then calling that in another method via the attribute using a string?**

This is a lot to digest and I hope it's not too overwhelming and I fully appreciate everyone's time.

Regards,

Comment: Just create a new attribute and read the values via reflection?

Comment: @germi I appreciate your input. A little direction with code? I have read many MSDN articles and cannot seem to find solid resources on creating a custom method attribute.

Comment: How about [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx)? If that doesn't help, you'd need to be more specific where your problem is.

Comment: @germi Thank you for the link, I have visited this one. Please forgive me as I am relatively new to "attributes". It appears that you either add an attribute to the class or bind an attribute to a method with values from a property. The idea is to have an attribute that's not related to the class, just a string that I can call. Hopefully that makes sense? Or am I missing the point haha

Comment: You could create an attribute `ContentAttribute` and decorate your methods with it. Then when you are looking for the right method to call, you iterate through your methods, looking for `ContentAttribute` on the method. If it is present, you get the value of the attribute (in your example `blog`), and handle it accordingly. The attribute could look something like this `[Content("blog")]`.